# Looking for a smartphone that has "good battery backup"? Why not "a good battery backup"?

Tags: articles, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> Looking for a smartphone that has "good battery backup"?

Why is it not "**a** good battery back up"? Why do we have to omit the article?

> If you are looking for a smartphone with a solid battery backup, here’s a list you can choose from.

In this sentence, the article "a" is used before solid battery backup. How is it countable here? Please explain.

Comment: Did you mean 'battery life'?

Comment: We would talk about **looking for backup** (meaning support) rather than **a backup**, unless we were referring to a person to back us up. The phrase has been carried over in your example. Moreover, most such announcements concentrate on getting the message across in as few words as possible.  Punters are concerned with clarity, not grammar, especially when each word costs. Don't look to newspapers and magazines for a grammar lesson.

Comment: I'm with Michael — not even sure what spec of the phone this refers to.

Comment: The spec of the phone is its property of being backed up, in the sense of supported. For a theoretical example, a desk phone that was typically used from its docking cradle but that has a reliable or high capacity reserve battery, would be “backed up” by the battery, and could have good battery backup. In this sense *backup* is an uncountable noun.

Comment: @djs - but the questioner asks about a smartphone, which would have an internal battery.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey certainly, but I’m not trying to give an opinion about smartphones, I’m trying to narrow in on what the phrase might mean if it were said. Whether or not it would be a reasonable thing to say is a different question!